# remove trailing zeros from and add decimal point to character string in Excel

Tags: excel, string, formatting, character

My values are combinations of numbers and letters. How do I
a) remove trailing zeros (up to 2; avoid removing more than 2 trailing zeros)
and 
b) put a decimal point after the 3rd character if there is 4 or more characters
?
Some example values:

```
A61
A6000
A6051
A6050
A610
A611
A6200
A6201
```

Comment: With those examples please show the expected output of each.

Comment: Is the length of your string always between 3 and 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you have provided:

```
=LEFT(A1,1) & MID(A1,2,LEN(A1))/10^(LEN(A1)-3)
```

[image]

Comment: That is SO much simpler than I had been doing. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MargaretMartin please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.